# Chaining delayed jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Let's say I have 2 servers, each running the same version of delayed jobs. Server 1 has a worker watching one queue A and Server 2 has 1 worker watching queue B. Both servers and all workers are looking at the same delayed jobs database.

What I want to happen is a chaining of the queues or workers. For instance, I will have a job that completes some kind of work on server 1 in queue A which sometimes results in another job that can only be executed on server 2. Currently, that second job which is assigned to queue B after server 1 completes its work  fails because it is attempting to find code that doesn't exist on server 1 that its worker is not aware of. I do have a max_run_time set for these jobs which results in the locked_at and locked_by to be cleared but max_attempts remains the same. Server 2's delayed job worker never attempts to pick up the job.

Is there a way to ensure that one job started by one worker is completed and can seamlessly be picked up by the secondary queue/worker?

Comment: Is the second job set to run on queue B?

Comment: @zetetic: Yes the second job is set to queue B. The number of attempts however remain the same which is 3 since that is what I currently have the max_attempts config set to in bin/delayed_job.